# How to Disable browser stop button near to back button in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, reload, blocking

I would like to prevent the user pressing the stop button in their browser while a certain page is loading. How can I do this in jquery or javascript?

Comment: you can't. you shouldn't. Consider changing your question to explain why you want to do such a hostile thing (it's my browser, not yours) and perhaps some one can help you drum up a better way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got this as a requirement. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable client browsers' native functionality like Back, Forward, Stop, Refresh, etc.  It's a good thing, too, because people would write web pages from which you couldn't navigate - or close the window - and you'd have to open task manager to kill the process every time.